# Merging maps in Gremlin

Tags: gremlin

I'm trying to write a single query that satisfies two requirements in the response object:

1. Must include *all* properties of a vertex, without specifying individual fields in the query.
2. Must flatten results at the same level on the object.

As separate queries, I can do:

#### 1. `valueMap` query

```
g.V(1)
.valueMap().by(unfold()).fold()
```

Response:

```json
{
  "property1": "value1",
  "property2": "value2"
}
```

#### 2. `project` query

```
g.V(1)
.project("projectedProperty")
.by(out("X").valueMap().by(unfold()).fold())
```

Response:

```json
{
  "projectedProperty": "value",
}
```

#### Combined query

I've attempted to use a union to combine these results:

```
g.V(1)
.union(
  valueMap().by(unfold()).fold(), // Query 1
  project("projectedField").by(out("X").valueMap().by(unfold()).fold()) // Query 2
).fold()
```

Response:

```json
{
  [
    {
      "property1": "value1",
      "property2": "value2"
    },
    {
      "projectedProperty": "value"
    }
  ]
}
```

This union approach relies on me putting a fold at the end, which in turn doesn't merge/flatten the two maps properly. Expected response is:

```json
{
  "property1": "value1",
  "property2": "value2",
  "projectedProperty": "value"
}
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this task of merging/flattening two maps in the response object?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The typical [pattern](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#collections) is to `unfold()` your maps to entries (keys/values) then `group()` them back together as one:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('person','name','marko').
......1>   union(project('count').by(outE().count()), elementMap()).
......2>   unfold().
......3>   group().by(keys).by(select(values))
==>[count:3,name:marko,label:person,id:1,age:29]
```

Comment: This worked, thank you. Specifically, I had to append `unfold().group().by(keys).by(select(values))` after the union.