# Azure Cosmos Graph nest edge vertex in a vertex property

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I have two vertex:

1) Vertex 1: `{ id: 1, name: “john” }`

2) Vertex 2: `{ id: 2, name: “mary” }`

There is an edge from 1 to 2 named “children”.

Is it possible to return 2 nested in 1 using gremlin like this?

```
  { 
    id: 1, 
    name: “john”,
    children: { id: 2, name: “mary” }
  }
```

Thank you!

My solution with an amazing help of @noam621 ---------------------------------

```
g.V(1)
.union( valueMap(true),
        project('children').by( coalesce( out('children').valueMap(true).fold() , constant([]))),
        project('parents').by( coalesce( out('parents').valueMap(true).fold() , constant([])))
)
.unfold().group().by(keys).by(select(values))
```

It returns the following object:

```
{ 
    id: 1, 
    name: [ “john” ],
    children: [ { id: 2, name: [ “mary” ] } ],
    parents: []
}
```

.union with project are the key to merge all objects in one object.
valueMap(true).fold() is fundamental to get all objects in the edge and coalesce helps with a default value if the edge doesn't return any vertex.

Due to some Azure Cosmos gremlin limitations is only possible to get values as array values.
Thus I finalized the object formatting in my application code. It's ok for now.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by using the `project` step for both vertexes:

```
g.V(1).project('id', 'name', 'children').
    by(id).
    by('name').
    by(out('children').
      project('id', 'name').by(id).
        by('name'))
```

example:
https://gremlify.com/3j

---

query with `valueMap`:

```
g.V(1).union(
    valueMap().
      with(WithOptions.tokens).by(unfold()),
    project('children').
      by(out('children').
        valueMap().
          with(WithOptions.tokens).by(unfold()))
  ).unfold().
  group().by(keys).
    by(select(values))
```

if `valueMap().with(WithOptions.tokens)` not supported in Cosmos use `valueMap(true)` instead

Comment: it's always better to prefer token based `by()` modulators, thus prefer `by(id)` to `by(id())` and `by("name")` to `by(values('name'))` - https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#steps-instead-of-tokens

Comment: Great!!! It works very well! :D Just one more question on this, is it possible to project to all properties instead of specifying each one? Thanks!!

Comment: @MuriloMacielCurti You can use `elementMap` or `valueMap` and then merge it with `project` only for the 'children' field. look here on merging maps:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60307292/merging-maps-in-gremlin

Comment: @noam621 I'm going to test here and I will return with the results. Thank you so much!

Comment: @noam621 I couldn't figure out how to achieve this. Can you share an example pls? I think elementMap is not available on Azure Cosmos Db. Thank you

Comment: @MuriloMacielCurti look at the new query I added

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211061/discussion-between-murilo-maciel-curti-and-noam621).